# Create an instance from .yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I have a Rails unit test for an Article class, I have an assertion to test the create! method.  I want to create the object from .yml data basically.  Like this:

In my yaml file .../test/fixtures/articles.yml:

```
one:
  id: 1
  title: MyText
  abstract: MyText
  place: MyString
  subject: MyString
```

And in article_test.rb :

```
def test_create_a_new_article
  assert Article.create!(articles(:one))
end
```

I keep getting `NoMethodError: undefined method`stringify_keys' for #<\Article:0x0000010819b640>`which I'm not surprised by, but how do call create! from the instance of Article created by articles(:one)?  I'm instantiating Article in my running code by passing params in a hash.  Would be great if I could just do something like: a`ssert Article.create!(articles(:one).to_hash)`

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you show us `articles` method? Or do you mean to say `articles[:one]`? Have you tried `articles['one']`?

Comment: @dmtri.com - This is standard fixture magic, methods are generated by rails.

Comment: @Slenny - Do not use fixtures, use factories! https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl

Comment: @BroiSatse - Thanks Broi, probably good to look at FactoryGirl at some point, but right now I want to avoid new dependencies and methodologies.

Comment: @Slenny - Once you try FactoryGirl you will not come back to fixtures. Have a read here: https://semaphoreapp.com/blog/2014/01/14/rails-testing-antipatterns-fixtures-and-factories.html. It is pretty common opinion in rails world, that we should not use fixtures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call articles(:one) your are getting back an Article object with the attributes defined in the fixture. This means you can use it as is i.e.

```
articles(:one).some_method
```

or assign it to a variable

```
article = articles(:one)
```

Basically rails fixture magic

EDIT

Article.create articles(:one).attributes.except("id")

Not sure if excluding the id is necessary

Comment: The question is, how to get a hash from fixture. :)

Comment: Thank you ob264, this worked.  I did try .attributes as it returns a nice hash, but did not think of the .except method, that was my problem.  Without that I kept getting: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::ConstraintException: PRIMARY KEY must be unique:....`   All good now, this solved it.

Answer (score 0):

After quite a lot of experimenting, it seems there is now straight forward way to do this. You can always load yaml directly:

```
def test_create_a_new_article
  attributes = YAML.load_file(File.join fixture_path, 'articles.yml')['one']
  assert Article.create!(articles(:one))
end
```

Comment: That's about the conclusion I had come to also, but ob264's answer above with the .except('id') works great.  .attributes returns a nice hash for my create method to use.

Comment: @Slenny - I remember I had some problem with `attributes` method returning or not returning some of the fields, can't remember what it was exactly now. But agree it should work and is much cleaner. Note however it might be problematic if you have uniqueness validator.